# ColdFusion 9 ORM Update multiple rows at one time

Tags: orm, coldfusion

Whats the best way to do a query like this, which will update more than one row:

```
UPDATE B
    SET col_a = 1
    Where col_a = 0
```

I can load the entities then loop them to do the EntitySave for each one, however this seems like overkill. Should I use HQL to do the update? Can I use HQL to do the update?

Comment: There are times where ORM doesn't make sense, and this could be one of them.  If it makes sense to run the update query, just use `<cfquery>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely run an update on more than one row using `ORMExecuteQuery`. This is an example of a project I worked on:

```
ORMExecuteQuery("UPDATE Part SET ReleaseDate = :ReleaseDate, ChangeNote = :ChangeNote WHERE ID IN (#Arguments.PartIDs#)", {ReleaseDate = Arguments.ReleaseDate, ChangeNote = Arguments.ChangeNote});
```

Easy as that... Notice that you specify the parameters as `:VarName` and feed them in as the second argument of the `ORMExecuteQuery` function.